# How to store a list of numbers in CSV file as integers in Neo4j

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I have a CSV file with the following numbers for example,

```
example.csv contains(Field A1):

1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10
```

I tried to use the following Neo4j code

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///example.csv" AS line
CREATE (d:Data) SET d.date= timestamp()
SET d.data = line WITH d
MATCH (t:Timestamp {name: "Digital"})
CREATE (d)<-[:HAS]-(t)
```

So in d.data, a list of strings is stored but I want a list of integers. I tried to use the code below but it gives an error.

```
SET d.data = toInt(line)
```

Is it possible to store the CSV data above in d.data as a list of integers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many lines do you have in your CSV file? Is it only a single line?

Comment: yes, it is a single line with 250 values. Without the toInt(line) i get a list of strings when i see the json form
"data" : ["1", "2"...] but i want a list of integers "data" : [1,2....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line` is a list of values, so you can use a [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) to convert each of its elements to an integer. If there are spaces in the strings, use [`trim`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-trim) to remove them (`ltrim` might also work, but the performance gains are minor).

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///example.csv" AS line
CREATE (d:Data) SET d.date = timestamp()
SET d.data = [value IN line | toInteger(trim(value))]
WITH d
MATCH (t:Timestamp {name: "Digital"})
CREATE (d)<-[:HAS]-(t)
```

(Note that the `line` variable is only a list if you do not use the [`WITH HEADERS`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file-containing-headers) option.)

Comment: I believe this will create a node on every single number in the CSV file, not a list of Integers in d.data

Comment: I get this error
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Collections containing null values can not be stored in properties. :(

Comment: Try listing the results first, i.e. `RETURN [value IN line | toInteger(value)]` and see what it shows.

Comment: okay it works only when the CSV file doesn't have spaces after comma ie. 1, 2, 3 instead the csv has to be saved like 1,2,3 so on. Is it possible to do with the spaces?

Comment: Sure, just [`trim`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-trim) the values. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could map a function to the list of string like so,

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///example.csv" AS line
CREATE (d:Data) SET d.date= timestamp()
SET d.data = extract(i in line | toInt(i)) WITH d
MATCH (t:Timestamp {name: "Digital"})
CREATE (d)<-[:HAS]-(t)
```

I'm not sure if cypher will automatically convert `line` to a list, but if it doesn't you can also try,

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///example.csv" AS line
CREATE (d:Data) SET d.date= timestamp()
SET d.data = extract(i in split(line,",") | toInt(i)) WITH d
MATCH (t:Timestamp {name: "Digital"})
CREATE (d)<-[:HAS]-(t)
```

Comment: I get this error
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected String but was List<String> (line 3, column 33 (offset: 117))
 "SET d.data = extract(i in split(line,",") | toInt(i)) WITH d" ^

Comment: go with the first query since cypher is already converting the string to a list